# Reincarnate in vs reincarnate into, which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

According to this,

[In-Into](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/in-into)

One of the usages of into is ,

> We use into after verbs describing change

Then it would seem "reincarnate into" would be more appropiate than "reincarnate in", however, both usages can be found being used (correctly or incorrectly) in internet

[Reincarnate in](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reincarnate%20in%22&ei=LEROX6yREMO_5OUP7em2UA&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwis1_H9_8frAhXDH7kGHe20DQoQ8tMDegQIDhAw&biw=1242&bih=597)

[Reincarnate into](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1242&bih=597&ei=RUROX_yCEtKV5OUPw8Cb0AQ&q=%22reincarnate%20into%22&oq=%22reincarnate%20into%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIICAAQBxAKEB4yBggAEAcQHjICCAAyBggAEAoQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHlDN8gxYsfMMYJX1DGgAcAB4AIABmQGIAfkBkgEDMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi8uemJgMjrAhXSCrkGHUPgBko4ChDh1QMIDQ&uact=5)

Reincarnate in vs reincarnate into, which one is correct? Can both be used?

Comment: I would have said the usual usage was _reincarnate as_ so perhaps we need more context about your use case.

Comment: Suppose you are writting the sypnosis of a movie and you want to say "a human who reincarnated into a demon" or "a human who reincarnated in a demon"

Answer (score 2):

Reincarnate is not a particularly common word in English but the usual usage is *reincarnate* as so in the example you quote in a comment one would say

> A human who was reincarnated as a demon

The only way I can say of using *in* is if you refer specifically to the soul and the body

> His soul was reincarnated in the body of a demon

In everyday language people are more likely to use a phrase like *come back as*

> With my bad luck I will probably come back as me
> He is so lazy he will come back as a three-toed sloth

Answer (score 0):

We generally use into when there is some motion, so it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Both 'reincarnate in' and 'reincarnate into' are correct.

The verb is usually used in passive voice.

be reincarnated in human form, be reincarnated in animal form,
be reincarnated into an earthly existence